# size of struct - size_t in c

Tags: c, struct, sizeof

For some reason I keep getting segmentation fault when I try to get the size of my struct.

```
struct my_struct {
  char *a;
  int  b;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct my_struct dastruct;
    size_t len = sizeof(dastruct) / sizeof(struct my_struct); // error
    qsort(dastruct, len, sizeof(struct my_struct), cmp);
    ...
}
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: `len` is equal to 1. What does `len` actually represent?!

Comment: Is that your *complete* code that gives you a segfault? I get no such error running that code.

Comment: Are you saying that you get a segfault at the division operation?

Comment: is not the complete code, it's kinda long to post. But I don't see anything on main that could cause a problem. Does the structure has to be filled with data prior getting the length?

Comment: This code demonstrates an attempt to sort one instance of my_struct? How do you expect anyone to figure out from that what is wrong with your real code?

Comment: answering your specific question. NO this code is correct ; sizeof does not need there to be data. The line you have flagged is not the cause of your crash. Almost certainly the qsort is failing becuase you have not passed it an array in param 1

Comment: @Josh: The size of the struct is given by `sizeof(dastruct)` (in your case) as well as by `sizeof(struct my_struct)`. Both produce the same value. Why you are dividing one by another (which will evaluate to 1), is completely unclear, unless you wanted `dastruct` to be an array (but it is not in your code).

Comment: Posting fake code almost never really works. As the question asker, you are unfortunately the least qualified to extract parts of the code to try and determine the problem. If you were qualified, you'd solve the problem in the process. So with that, it's best to take the problem code and cut chunks out while the problem still remains. Keep track of what you cut out and try to use that to determine the problem. Only after you still cannot figure it out, post here to get more eyes on the problem. But when you post fake code, we solve fake problems.

Comment: WHICH line is crashing? The one with `sizeof`?

Answer (score 2):

If you are getting the crash specifically at the

```
size_t len = sizeof(dastruct) / sizeof(struct my_struct);
```

line, it might be caused by `sizeof(struct my_struct)` evaluating to 0. (I.e the problem is actually the division by zero). This might happen in some compilers when type `struct my_struct` is incomplete, i.e. it is not defined. Using incomplete type in `sizeof` is illegal in C, but some compilers allow it for some reason, evaluating it to 0. (Although I'd expect the compiler to catch this division by 0 at compile time.)

Your code is obviously fake and doesn't illustrate the problem. If the above theory is correct, most likely in your real code you either mistyped the name of the type `struct my_struct` in `sizeof` or forgot to include the definition of the type `struct my_struct`.

(Highly unlikely, but anyway...)

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to make `dastruct` an array.

```
   struct my_struct dastruct[10];
```

Edit: You've also not given `cmp`, so its not possible to say if something is wrong there (which I see would be the place the segmentation fault occurs).

Comment: I did comment //qsort(dastruct, len, sizeof(struct my_struct), cmp); and still same problem

Comment: @Josh: In that case your code is fine. There's nothing that can cause a segmentation fault in it. You either posting a fake code or incomplete code. Post the real code.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can possibly see is that you forgot to `#include <stdlib.h>`. Remember that C implicitly declares a `qsort` at the first use.

Comment: I do have #include <stdlib.h>

Answer (score 0):

If your code as posted is your complete code, then you have failed to initialise the `a` pointer member of `dastruct`, so it's pointing off into some invalid location. When `qsort()` calls `cmp()` which presumably uses that pointer (you haven't shown that code), you are likely to get a segfault.

Note that I'm assuming your segfault happens at some place *other than* the initialisation of `len` that only divides two constants (which is likely to happen at compile time anyway).